# Remote Desktop over LAN without Internet access

Tags: networking, dns, remote-desktop

Im lookin for a way to Remote Desktop my Laptop.
Connection with Ethernet and ADSL Modem/Router
PC connect by LAN1
Laptop by LAN2
PC=DNS Server with 192.168.1.1
Laptop ip = 192.168.1.6

---

Connect Laptop in LAN2 and RemoteDesktop work Fine.
but I want Laptop not Access to Internet.

Comment: please take the time to explain your setup more clearly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

configure your laptop ipstats to static and dont enter any gateway or dns, just provide ip and subnet:

ipconf of laptop

```
    ip:192.168.1.6
    subnet:255.255.x.x
    gateway: leave empty
    dns: leave emtpy
```